# Real Analysis - Cauchy Condensation Test

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Prove that the series converges and find an upper bound on $\alpha$.

$\alpha$:= $\sum_{n=10^{10}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nlog_{10}(n)log_{10}(log_{10}(n))^3}$

This is my work: [http://imgur.com/a/3K1vx](https://imgur.com/a/3K1vx)

I'm really bad with logarithmic functions so I'm not really sure how I did, would someone mind checking my work please? Also, what would the upper bound be and how do you find that?

Comment: Do you mean $\alpha:= \sum_{n=10^{10}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nlog_{10}(n)\left(log_{10}(log_{10} n)\right)^3}$?

Comment: the first one but with parenthesis around the last $n$ like how i wrote it

Comment: But it seems to me that what you wrote above is different from what you wrote in the image.

Comment: oh wow you're right, i just noticed that

Comment: With the integral test you would get using $u=\log_{10}\log_{10}x$ and $u'(x)=\frac1{\ln(10)\log_{10}x}·\frac1{\ln(10)x}$ $$α\le\int_{10^10}^\infty\frac{dx}{x\log_{10}(x)[\log_{10}\log_{10}x]^3}=\int_1^\infty\frac{[\ln(10)]^2\,du}{u^3}=\frac12[\ln(10)]^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ between $10^k$ and $10^{k+1}$ you get
$$
\frac1{10^{k+1}·(k+1)·[\log_{10}(k+1)]^3}\le a_n\le \frac1{10^k·k·[\log_{10}(k)]^3}
$$
There are $10^{k+1}-10^k=9·10^k$ elements in that index segment if you exclude one of the endpoints. Summation gives thus
$$
\frac{9·10^k}{10^{k+1}·(k+1)·[\log_{10}(k+1)]^3}
\le\sum_{n=10^k+1}^{10^{k+1}} a_n
\le \sum_{n=10^k}^{10^{k+1}-1} a_n
\le\frac{9·10^k}{10^k·k·[\log_{10}(k)]^3}
$$
Thus
$$
\frac1{10^{11}}+\frac{9}{10}\sum_{k=11}^\infty \frac1{k[\log_{10}(k)]^3}\le α
\le 9\sum_{k=10}^\infty \frac{1}{k[\log_{10}(k)]^3}
$$
Then condensate once more.
$$
\frac9{10}\sum_{\ell=2}^\infty\frac1{\ell^3}
\le\sum_{k=10^1+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k[\log_{10}(k)]^3},\quad
\sum_{k=10^1}^\infty \frac{1}{k[\log_{10}(k)]^3}
\le 9\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\frac1{\ell^3}
$$

---

In total you get for the upper bound
\begin{align}
 α&\le\sum_{k=10}^\infty\frac{9·10^k}{10^k·k·[\log_{10}(k)]^3}
=9·\sum_{k=10}^\infty \frac{1}{k[\log_{10}(k)]^3}\\
&\le9\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\frac{9·10^\ell}{10^\ell·\ell^3}
=81·\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\ell^3}\\
&\le 81·\left(1+\sum_{\ell=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\ell^3-\ell}\right)
=81·\left(1+\frac12\lim_{L\to\infty}\left(\frac1{1·2}-\frac1{L(L+1)}\right)\right)=\frac{405}4
\end{align}

Comment: haven't seen it done like this before ? not discrediting you but im just unfamiliar with this

Comment: Look into the wikipedia article at the end for alternative subdivisions. But the general proof follows the estimates in my first lines.

Comment: im still a little lost, can you help me please?

Comment: At what point do you need help? You could of course also stay with the dyadic powers, the expressions then get a little messy, as you already experienced.

Comment: just the rest of the answer please, i tried looking up what you said and i dont really follow half of it, i gave the question an honest attempt, i am more of a visual learner and learn best by just seeing the problem done out, can you please help me out i have a test on this later this week ?

Comment: The first you need to correct in your calculation is that $$\sum_{n=10^{10}}a_n\le \sum_{k=\lfloor 10·\log_2(10)\rfloor}2^ka_{2^k}.$$ Then the third power never leaves the exponent.

Comment: shouldnt there be another log base 10 in the middle of the denominator in the beginning of your work?

Comment: It is inserting $n=10^k$ into $$n\log_{10}n[\log_{10}\log_{10}n]^3 = 10^k\log_{10}(10^k)[\log_{10}\log_{10}(10^k)]^3 \\ =10^k·k\log_{10}(10)·[\log_{10}(k\log_{10}(10))]^3= 10^k·k·[\log_{10}(k)]^3, $$ thus the losing of 2 times $\log$ in the first substitution.

Comment: thank you, this is the complete answer correct?